# Array of Mongodb Document only show ObjectId

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, nestjs

So I want to update a document in Mongo.
I have a document and I want to modify it and send it back. But for some reason, when I do, it changes the value into ObjectId. And I figured out an alternative, but I don't like it...

```js
  async updateDogs() {
    const cats = await this.catModel.find().exec();

    const dog: DogDocument = await this.dogModel
      .findOne({ _id: '62b57f65fa0e953b3e0494eb' })
      .populate('cats')
      .exec();

    console.log('All cats:', cats);
    console.log('Dingo Dog in find', dog);

    dog.cats = cats;

    console.log('Dingo dog in find but with Cat ObjectId()', dog.cats);
    console.log(dog.cats[0].name);

    dog.cats = [];
    dog.cats.push(...cats);

    console.log('Dingo dog in find and with cat', dog.cats);
    console.log(dog.cats[0].name);
  }
```

And this is the output:

```
All cats: [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62af2508025adb0b7e6e446f"),
    name: 'Mikey',
    age: 0,
    breed: 'string',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62b57fd0fa0e953b3e0494f5"),
    name: 'Mini',
    age: 0,
    breed: 'string',
    __v: 0
  }
]
Dingo Dog in find {
  _id: new ObjectId("62b57f65fa0e953b3e0494eb"),
  name: 'Dingo',
  age: 0,
  __v: 0,
  cats: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("62af2508025adb0b7e6e446f"),
      name: 'Mikey',
      age: 0,
      breed: 'string',
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
}
Dingo dog in find but with Cat ObjectId() [
  new ObjectId("62af2508025adb0b7e6e446f"),
  new ObjectId("62b57fd0fa0e953b3e0494f5")
]
First cat name is undefined
Dingo dog in find and with cat [
  {
    name: 'Mikey',
    age: 0,
    breed: 'string',
    _id: new ObjectId("62af2508025adb0b7e6e446f"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Mini',
    age: 0,
    breed: 'string',
    _id: new ObjectId("62b57fd0fa0e953b3e0494f5"),
    __v: 0
  }
]
First cat name is Mikey
```

The way i add cats to dog.cats it change the result.

Do you have any idea why ? I Need to have CatDocument and not ObjectId.
And i can do another populate but i don't want to make another request because i already have it. And use `push` is ugly i think...

Comment: Would the [`lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) method solve your problem?

Comment: @boranseckin no, it's didn't solve my problem